# Cookie won't change on first visit to subdomain in IE only

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, subdomain

I have this very simple code

```
<?php
var_dump($_COOKIE);
setcookie("TestCookie", 'Value1', time()+3600, '/', $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]);
die();
?>
```

The same code run on both myDomain.com and sub.myDomain.com

The first time I load the page, the vardump is empty, but the second time, I have the TestCookie variables on it. On Chrome, Firefox, Safari and many other, it work both on myDomain.com and sub.myDomain.com.

But in IE, if I go to mydomain.com and then go to sub.mydomain.com, the cookie is kinda freeze there, on sub.mydomain.com if I change the value of the cookie to "Value2" it will still be display "Value1" until I change it on mydomain.com. (I did multiple reload to be sure the var_dump really take the cookie)

If I close IE and directly go to sub.mydomain.com without visiting mydomain.com I can change the cookie without any issue, the problem only happend when I first visit mydomain.com and then sub.mydomain.com, and of course, only on IE (tested IE8 to IE11)

Any idea on how I can fix this?

Edit: After some digging around, if I look at the header sended by the browser in IE with the function getallheaders(), in the "Cookie" section, I get both value 'TestCookie=Test2; TestCookie=Test3', so IE send both the cookie of the subdomain and the main domain, but PHP will read only the first one. So only the cookie based on the main domain.

Comment: @PeeHaa I do not wish to share the cookie value between domains/subdomains. If possible I'll use the same cookie name but with different value on each subdomain.

Comment: @PeeHaa I tried with the server name and an empty string... work fine on every single browser, but not IE :(

Comment: Sorry. That's all I can think of right now.